How to prevent the anonymous user from being the author of a custom entity type?
I am making a module that stores push notification tokens as a custom entity type.
Because of the nature of push notification tokens (sending a notification to the user's device, like an email address), it doesn't make sense to let the anonymous user be the author of a token entity. So, how can I prevent the anonymous user from being set as the author?
I could write a custom validation constraint but I am wondering if core provides something to handle this situation.

I decided to fix this in the preSave() method:
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function preSave(EntityStorageInterface $storage): void {
    parent::preSave($storage);
    $owner_id = $this->getOwnerId();
    if (!is_int($owner_id)) {
      throw new PushNotificationsRegistrationTokensInvalidArgumentException("Owner ID for push notification token not set!");
    }
    elseif ($owner_id === 0) {
      throw new PushNotificationsRegistrationTokensInvalidArgumentException("Anonymous cannot be owner of push notification token!");
    }
  }

Since drush generate entity:content adds a preSave() method that sets $owner_id to 0 if none is specified, I decided this would be a good place to enforce the constraint of "do not allow the anonymous user to be the author."
